# Force no cache for unregistered users

Tags: 7, caching

Is there a way to force a fresh page to be served to unregistered users every time instead of the local cached version?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off caching by going to Configuration > Performance, and uncheck "Cache pages for anonymous users."  That will turn off page caching for the whole site.

If you only want to keep specific pages from being cached you can use [Cache Exclude](http://drupal.org/project/cacheexclude).

You can also (**but it is not recommended**; see the comments) enter this PHP snippet into the page's template, for example node--123.tpl.php.

```
// Keep the page from being cached
$GLOBALS['conf']['cache'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Checkout http://drupal.org/project/cacheexclude if you just want a module to do this for you.

Comment: I would give +1 for the first part of the answer, but -1 for the suggestion to exclude pages from cache in the theme layer. The theme layer is for presentation, not behavior. Once you start putting stuff like this in your theme, you cannot change themes anymore without breaking things.

Answer (score 0):

The expression *local cache* suggests that op is referring to the browser cache. If this is the case then navigate to *Administration » Configuration » Development » Performance* and set **Expiration of cached pages** to **none**.

Before testing the new configuration reset your browser cache.